# Divs keep moving around seemingly at random

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I have 10 different overlapping divs, and whenever I adjust the screen size, the elements move seemingly unrelated to each other, even though they're all positioned as absolute.

I've tried just focusing on the video div and the container div (That's why they're the only two divs with percentage spacing) to keep their sizes proportional, but I just cannot seem to get it after about 2 weeks of fiddling.

Any help is appreciated.
html:

```css
#video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 60%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: cover;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: cover;
}

#hand {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 600px;
  left: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#load {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#email {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 550px;
  right: 600px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 00px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#cv {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 430px;
  right: 700px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 00px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#channel {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: 1px solid white;
  display: inline-block;
}

#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: 0px;
}

#button2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black">
  <div id="video">
    <video id="content" width=50% height=auto autoplay muted>
        <source src="friend.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="Clayvision.png" width=100% height=auto>
  </div>
  <div id="hand">
    <video id="control">
            <source src="hand1.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
  </div>
  <div id="load">
    <video id="loading" muted autoplay loop>
            <source src="Loading.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
  </div>
  <div id="email">
    <a href="noahmreiner@gmail.com">
      <video id="gmail">
            <source src="gmail.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="cv">
    <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-taF_MrzsHWSm05RJ5EyMe1Y0eZkFcTm/view?usp=sharing">
      <video id="resume">
            <source src="resume.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="channel"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the HTML? Although, looking at this, I can't see any place that you have given the topmost parent element a height/width, and I don't see anywhere that has `relative` positioning, which could be your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tammy! What a total dingbat I am... forgetting the html. Just edited it. And even changing that relative to absolute, I still have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioned elements will move according to a fixed distance from the window border. So when you resize the window, all divs will move randomly because they aren't moving relatively to one another. To solve this, simply change all postition: absolute to

```
position: relative;
```

and then use a grid system like [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Comment: I was thinking if I position all the elements within the container element, then I can make only the container "relative" and the inside elements "absolute". Is that incorrect logic?

Comment: @Noah for all the elements to have the same relation to another regardless of window size, you need to implement `position: relative`. The container will be resized according to the window, so your proposed solution will not work either.

Comment: thanks @Karl. If all my elements are relative, don't I know longer have control of the top, bottom, left, and right characteristics?

Comment: @Noah No you don't, if you don't use a grid system (check the initial answer) the elements inside the container will be placed in order of the html.

Comment: @Noah could you please mark my answer as a solution?